# JasperReport base-report template shared across multiple reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I use Jasper Report to design invoice/offer/order reports for few companies. As you might understand, each company wants its own logo in the report, its own "frontend" customisations, etc. But the db query, such as other "backend" logics are the same across all companies.

What I'm doing right now is creating a dedicated "invoice" report for each company. Which works, but on the long run it might cause big issue in mantaining reports: imagine I'll serve 1000 companies and all of a sudden I'm going to find a bug in my query. In order to fix the bug on all my clients I'll have to open one by one each "invoice" report of each client and fix it. Sounds not that good...

Would be lovely if I can define the query once, store it on my Jasper Server and refer to this query by each of my reports. But couldn't find this feature so far....is it possible? Any suggestion to address this problem?

Thanks,
Guido

Comment: In jasper studio, you can create a query, and use it as a link in your reports. If you have a single jasper-server for all companies, for an update you will just have to published the modified query on the server ... unless you modify the outcome, it should be rather easy.

Comment: Thanks, not sure I've fully understood. Do you mean I can create a "query", store it on Jasper Server and use this query across different reports? Thanks

Comment: _A JasperReport uses a query to select the data to be returned from the data source. You can define the query in the JRXML itself, but you can also create and save queries in the repository. A query saved in the repository can be re-used by multiple JasperReports._ [link](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-administrator-guide/v630/queries)

Comment: Cool, that's exactly what I was looking for! Following the guide you linked I have been able to add a "query" to my repo. But now I'm not understanding how can I configure my report to use that query. I'm using Jasper Studio, and when I right-click on my report I can choose "Dataset & Query" but from the dialog box that opens I can only write my own query, I cannot pick one from the repo. Any advice? Thanks